# the connection cannt be used to perform this operation. It may closed or not valid in this context error in vb6

Tags: vb6, adodb

I am trying to execute the query which stores recordset vales in sql db. when I am trying to execute that i am getting error like

the connection cannt be used to perform this operation. It may closed or not valid in this context  error in vb6. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
' Write records to Database

    frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "Loading data into database......"
    Call FindServerConnection_NoMsg

    Dim lngRecCount As Long
    lngRecCount = 0
    rcdDNE.MoveFirst

    Set rcdReclamation = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rcdReclamation
        .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .Source = "insert into t_DATA_DneFrc (RTN, AccountNbr, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Amount) values ('" & rcdDNE("RTN") & "', '" & rcdDNE("AccountNbr") & "', '" & rcdDNE("FirstName") & "', '" & rcdDNE("MiddleName") & "', '" & rcdDNE("LastName") & "', '" & rcdDNE("Amount") & "')"
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open cmdCommand
    End With

    Do Until rcdDNE.EOF
        lngRecCount = lngRecCount + 1
        frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "Adding record " & lngRecCount & " of " & rcdDNE.RecordCount & " to database."
        frmDNELoad.Refresh
        DoEvents
        Call CommitNew
        rcdDNE.MoveNext
    Loop

    frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "DNE Processing Complete."
    frmDNELoad.Refresh

End Function

Sub CommitNew()
   ' Add records to DneFrc table
    With rcdReclamation
        .Requery
        .AddNew
        .Fields![RTN] = rcdDNE.Fields![RTN]
        .Fields![AccountNbr] = rcdDNE.Fields![AccountNbr]
        .Fields![FirstName] = rcdDNE.Fields![FirstName]
        .Fields![MiddleName] = rcdDNE.Fields![MiddleName]
        .Fields![LastName] = rcdDNE.Fields![LastName]
        .Fields![Amount] = rcdDNE.Fields![Amount]
        .Update

    End With

End Sub
```

conection  code

```
Sub InstantiateCommand_SQLText()
    ' Creates a command object to be used when executing SQL statements.
    Set objCommSQLText = New ADODB.Command
    objCommSQLText.ActiveConnection = objConn
    objCommSQLText.CommandType = adCmdText
End Sub

Function FindServerConnection_NoMsg() As String

    Dim rcdClientPaths As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strDBTemp As String
    Const CLIENT_UPDATE_DIR = "\\PSGSPHX02\NORS\Rs\ClientUpdate\"

    On Error Resume Next
    ' If persisted recordset is not there, try and copy one down from
    ' CLIENT_UPDATE_DIR.  If that can't be found, create a blank one
    ' and ask the user for the server name.
    Set rcdClientPaths = New ADODB.Recordset
    ' Does it already exist locally?
    If FileExists_FullPath(App.Path & "\" & "t_PCD_ServerConnectionList.xml") = False Then
        ' Can it be retrieved from CLIENT_UPDATE_DIR
        If Dir(CLIENT_UPDATE_DIR & "t_PCD_ServerConnectionList.xml")  "" Then
            FileCopy CLIENT_UPDATE_DIR & "t_PCD_ServerConnectionList.xml", App.Path & "\" & "t_PCD_ServerConnectionList.xml"
        Else
            ' Creat a blank one.
            With rcdClientPaths
                .Fields.Append "ServerConnection", adVarChar, 250
                .Fields.Append "Description", adVarChar, 50
                .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
                .LockType = adLockOptimistic
                .CursorLocation = adUseClient
                .Open
                .Save App.Path & "\" & "t_PCD_ServerConnectionList.xml", adPersistXML
                .Close
            End With
        End If
    End If

    ' Open the recordset
    With rcdClientPaths
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open App.Path & "\" & "t_PCD_ServerConnectionList.xml", , , , adCmdFile
    End With

    If rcdClientPaths.RecordCount  0 Then
        ' try each one listed
        rcdClientPaths.MoveFirst
        Do Until rcdClientPaths.EOF
            strDBTemp = TryConnection_NoMsg(rcdClientPaths.Fields![serverconnection])
            If strDBTemp  "" Then
                FindServerConnection_NoMsg = strDBTemp
                Exit Function
            End If
            rcdClientPaths.MoveNext
        Loop
        strDBTemp = ""
    End If

    Do While strDBTemp = ""
        If strDBTemp  "" Then
            strDBTemp = TryConnection_NoMsg(strDBTemp)
            If strDBTemp  "" Then
                With rcdClientPaths
                    .AddNew
                    .Fields![serverconnection] = strDBTemp
                    .Update
                    .Save
                End With
                FindServerConnection_NoMsg = strDBTemp
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
End Function

Function TryConnection_NoMsg(ByVal SvName As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' If a server was provided, try to open a connection to it.
    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
    With objConn
        .CommandTimeout = 30
        .ConnectionTimeout = 30
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Server=" & SvName & "; User ID=RS_Auth; Password=weLcomers_auth; Initial Catalog=NORS" ' Test
        .Open
        .Close
    End With
    Set objConn = Nothing
    TryConnection_NoMsg = SvName
    Screen.MousePointer = vbNormal
    Exit Function

ErrHandle:
    TryConnection_NoMsg = ""
    Set objConn = Nothing
    Screen.MousePointer = vbNormal
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Couple of things: Could you please format the rest of the code so it looks as nice as the first part?  Also, where does the error occur in your code?

Comment: @pbrp: I rolled back your last edit, as you deleted some pertinent code (and totally messed up the formatting of all the code). Please learn to format code if you're going to edit the post; there's help available right from the edit page.

Comment: When do you get this error? On which action?

Comment: Faaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaar too much code. Cut this down to the MINIMUM amount of code you need to reproduce your error.

Comment: I believe I am getting problem here. cmdCommand is not opening. There I am getting error. I believe there is problem in .commandType = adCmdtext

With cmdCommand
        .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CommandText = "query here"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With
    
    Set rcdReclamation = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rcdReclamation
        .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open cmdCommand
    End With

Comment: @pbrp: Dude, rather than posting every line of the program you are having trouble with, try to isolate the problem to the shortest amount of code it takes to re-produce it. Then you would either 1) have identified the problem yourself or 2) have much less code to post, which means more people will read it, which means you will more likely get a good answer. So cutting it down to the minimum can help. Please do this in future rather than re-posting the same poor question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have already closed the connection here in `TryConnection_NoMsg` function (?)

```
 With objConn
        .CommandTimeout = 30
        .ConnectionTimeout = 30
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Server=" & SvName & "; Database=NORS; User ID=RS_Auth; Password=weLcomers_auth; Initial Catalog=NORS" ' Test
        .Open
        .Close
```

Comment: but i opened connection again in InstantiateCommand_SP() method

Comment: But have you called the function? I cant see  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that `FindServerConnection_NoMsg` is not managing to open the connection, and since it ends in `NoMsg` that you're not seeing the error about why the connection wasn't opened. You then go on to just use the connection without knowing that the open failed.

Post the code for `FindServerConnection_NoMsg`.

BTW, your question itself should have given you a clue. It specifically says that the connection can't be used, and that it may not be open. That should have told you where to start looking, and at the least told you you should have posted the code that opened the connection as part of your question.

Comment: Remove the line ON ERROR RESUME NEXT from FindServerConnection_NoMsg and run your code. The error message should tell you what the problem is, and why it's happening. ON ERROR RESUME NEXT basically means "ignore any errors and don't tell me about them", which is exactly what's causing you to not know what's happening.

Comment: I don't have VB6 available anywhere, so you'll have to see if someone else spots something. In the meantime, you know the problem is that the connection can't be opened (or is closed somewhere it shouldn't be); try stepping through the code in the debugger starting in FindServerConnection_NoMsg and see where exactly it's failing. That should give you an idea of where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone. I sloved my problem. This what i cahnge in my code

Dim lngRecCount As Long
    lngRecCount = 0
    rcdDNE.MoveFirst

```
 With cmdCommand
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    .CommandText = "insert into t_DATA_DneFrc (RTN, AccountNbr, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Amount) values ('" & rcdDNE("RTN") & "', '" & rcdDNE("AccountNbr") & "', '" & rcdDNE("FirstName") & "', '" & rcdDNE("MiddleName") & "', '" & rcdDNE("LastName") & "', '" & rcdDNE("Amount") & "')"
    .CommandType = adCmdText

End With

Set rcddnefrc = New ADODB.Recordset
With rcddnefrc
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM T_DATA_DNEFRC"
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open
End With

Do Until rcdDNE.EOF
    lngRecCount = lngRecCount + 1
    frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "Adding record " & lngRecCount & " of " & rcdDNE.RecordCount & " to database."
    frmDNELoad.Refresh
    DoEvents
    Call CommitNew
    rcdDNE.MoveNext
Loop

frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "DNE Processing Complete."
frmDNELoad.Refresh
```